# how to make clustering strategy in openlayer 3

Tags: openlayers-3

[Help]
Hi all, can we implement strategy in cluster like openlayer 2? I don't find any example to cluster with strategy in openlayer3. I want to cluster only a feature which have the same class like openlayer 2 do in example : http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html .. How to code it in openlayer 3? thx

Comment: Have you tried using [geometryFunction](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html)?

Comment: Can you give a simple example for me? I don't find a function for make strategy in cluster openlayers 3 like openlayers 2 do.